# Como deixar uma props opcional em um componente do React JS?

Tags: react, map

Tem um compoente que recebe as propriedades de um json como props, entretanto esse componente terá de receber propriedades de outro json quando o tema mudar. A questão é que no primeiro json tem imagem e nesse novo não tem imagem, como poderia resolver?
Segue o codigo abaixo:

````
  ```
    <Card
      
      title={currentData[index].title}
      description={currentData[index].description}
      image={currentData[index].image}
    />
  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um operador lógico dentro do elemento Card pra testar se existe algum valor sendo passado na sua props.image.

Por exemplo:

```
<img src={props.image && outraImagem} />
```

Nesse exemplo, se existir "props.image" vai ser mostrado, se não existir vai mostrar "outraImagem".